# How install simplesaml on Wamp as an SP

Tags: php, saml, saml-2.0

I want implement SSO for my Website (Wordpress and an ADFS).
For this, I use simplesamlphp as on SP (ADFS is the idP).

To test simplesamlphp, I download the package and I install in wamp (D:\wamp\www\simplesamlphp).
I read this tuto (http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.10/simplesamlphp-install), so I have create an Alias and configure config.php.

But, when i want to test this configuration, I see this error : "Not Found The requested URL /simplesaml/www/module.php/core/frontpage_welcome.php was not found on this server".

What is wrong here ?

Config.php:

```
<?php
/* 
 * The configuration of simpleSAMLphp
 * 
 * $Id: config.php 3171 2012-09-25 08:54:06Z jaimepc@gmail.com $
 */

$config = array (

/**
 * Setup the following parameters to match the directory of your installation.
 * See the user manual for more details.
 *
 * Valid format for baseurlpath is:
 * [(http|https)://(hostname|fqdn)[:port]]/[path/to/simplesaml/]
 * (note that it must end with a '/')
 *
 * The full url format is useful if your simpleSAMLphp setup is hosted behind
 * a reverse proxy. In that case you can specify the external url here.
 *
 * Please note that simpleSAMLphp will then redirect all queries to the
 * external url, no matter where you come from (direct access or via the
 * reverse proxy).
 */
'baseurlpath'           => 'simplesaml/www/',
'certdir'               => 'cert/',
'loggingdir'            => 'log/',
'datadir'               => 'data/',

/*
 * A directory where simpleSAMLphp can save temporary files.
 *
 * SimpleSAMLphp will attempt to create this directory if it doesn't exist.
 */
'tempdir'               => '/tmp/simplesaml',


/*
 * If you enable this option, simpleSAMLphp will log all sent and received messages
 * to the log file.
 *
 * This option also enables logging of the messages that are encrypted and decrypted.
 *
 * Note: The messages are logged with the DEBUG log level, so you also need to set
 * the 'logging.level' option to LOG_DEBUG.
 */
'debug' => FALSE,


'showerrors'            =>  TRUE,

/**
 * Custom error show function called from SimpleSAML_Error_Error::show.
 * See docs/simplesamlphp-errorhandling.txt for function code example.
 *
 * Example:
 *   'errors.show_function' => array('sspmod_example_Error_Show', 'show'),
 */

/**
 * This option allows you to enable validation of XML data against its
 * schemas. A warning will be written to the log if validation fails.
 */
'debug.validatexml' => FALSE,

/**
 * This password must be kept secret, and modified from the default value 123.
 * This password will give access to the installation page of simpleSAMLphp with
 * metadata listing and diagnostics pages.
 * You can also put a hash here; run "bin/pwgen.php" to generate one.
 */
'auth.adminpassword'        => 'tdRWrP1y',
'admin.protectindexpage'    => false,
'admin.protectmetadata'     => false,

/**
 * This is a secret salt used by simpleSAMLphp when it needs to generate a secure hash
 * of a value. It must be changed from its default value to a secret value. The value of
 * 'secretsalt' can be any valid string of any length.
 *
 * A possible way to generate a random salt is by running the following command from a unix shell:
 * tr -c -d '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' </dev/urandom | dd bs=32 count=1 2>/dev/null;echo
 */
'secretsalt' => 'defaultsecretsalt',

/*
 * Some information about the technical persons running this installation.
 * The email address will be used as the recipient address for error reports, and
 * also as the technical contact in generated metadata.
 */
'technicalcontact_name'     => 'Nicolas Vergnes',
'technicalcontact_email'    => 'nvergnes@hotmail.fr',

/*
 * The timezone of the server. This option should be set to the timezone you want
 * simpleSAMLphp to report the time in. The default is to guess the timezone based
 * on your system timezone.
 *
 * See this page for a list of valid timezones: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
 */
'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',

/*
 * Logging.
 * 
 * define the minimum log level to log
 *      SimpleSAML_Logger::ERR      No statistics, only errors
 *      SimpleSAML_Logger::WARNING  No statistics, only warnings/errors
 *      SimpleSAML_Logger::NOTICE   Statistics and errors
 *      SimpleSAML_Logger::INFO     Verbose logs
 *      SimpleSAML_Logger::DEBUG    Full debug logs - not reccomended for production
 * 
 * Choose logging handler.
 * 
 * Options: [syslog,file,errorlog]
 * 
 */
'logging.level'         => SimpleSAML_Logger::NOTICE,
'logging.handler'       => 'syslog',

/*
 * Choose which facility should be used when logging with syslog.
 *
 * These can be used for filtering the syslog output from simpleSAMLphp into its
 * own file by configuring the syslog daemon.
 *
 * See the documentation for openlog (http://php.net/manual/en/function.openlog.php) for available
 * facilities. Note that only LOG_USER is valid on windows.
 *
 * The default is to use LOG_LOCAL5 if available, and fall back to LOG_USER if not.
 */
'logging.facility' => defined('LOG_LOCAL5') ? constant('LOG_LOCAL5') : LOG_USER,

/*
 * The process name that should be used when logging to syslog.
 * The value is also written out by the other logging handlers.
 */
'logging.processname' => 'simplesamlphp',

/* Logging: file - Logfilename in the loggingdir from above.
 */
'logging.logfile'       => 'simplesamlphp.log',

/* (New) statistics output configuration.
 *
 * This is an array of outputs. Each output has at least a 'class' option, which
 * selects the output.
 */
'statistics.out' => array(
    // Log statistics to the normal log.
    /*
    array(
        'class' => 'core:Log',
        'level' => 'notice',
    ),
    */
    // Log statistics to files in a directory. One file per day.
    /*
    array(
        'class' => 'core:File',
        'directory' => '/var/log/stats',
    ),
    */
),


/*
 * Enable
 * 
 * Which functionality in simpleSAMLphp do you want to enable. Normally you would enable only 
 * one of the functionalities below, but in some cases you could run multiple functionalities.
 * In example when you are setting up a federation bridge.
 */
'enable.saml20-idp'     => true,
'enable.shib13-idp'     => false,
'enable.adfs-idp'       => false,
'enable.wsfed-sp'       => false,
'enable.authmemcookie' => false,

/* 
 * This value is the duration of the session in seconds. Make sure that the time duration of
 * cookies both at the SP and the IdP exceeds this duration.
 */
'session.duration'      =>  8 * (60*60), // 8 hours.
'session.requestcache'  =>  4 * (60*60), // 4 hours

/*
 * Sets the duration, in seconds, data should be stored in the datastore. As the datastore is used for
 * login and logout requests, thid option will control the maximum time these operations can take.
 * The default is 4 hours (4*60*60) seconds, which should be more than enough for these operations.
 */
'session.datastore.timeout' => (4*60*60), // 4 hours

/*
 * Sets the duration, in seconds, auth state should be stored.
 */
'session.state.timeout' => (60*60), // 1 hour

/*
 * Option to override the default settings for the session cookie name
 */
'session.cookie.name' => 'SimpleSAMLSessionID',

/*
 * Expiration time for the session cookie, in seconds.
 *
 * Defaults to 0, which means that the cookie expires when the browser is closed.
 *
 * Example:
 *  'session.cookie.lifetime' => 30*60,
 */
'session.cookie.lifetime' => 0,

/*
 * Limit the path of the cookies.
 *
 * Can be used to limit the path of the cookies to a specific subdirectory.
 *
 * Example:
 *  'session.cookie.path' => '/simplesaml/',
 */
'session.cookie.path' => '/',

/*
 * Cookie domain.
 *
 * Can be used to make the session cookie available to several domains.
 *
 * Example:
 *  'session.cookie.domain' => '.example.org',
 */
'session.cookie.domain' => NULL,

/*
 * Set the secure flag in the cookie.
 *
 * Set this to TRUE if the user only accesses your service
 * through https. If the user can access the service through
 * both http and https, this must be set to FALSE.
 */
'session.cookie.secure' => FALSE,

/*
 * When set to FALSE fallback to transient session on session initialization
 * failure, throw exception otherwise.
 */
'session.disable_fallback' => FALSE,

/*
 * Enable secure POST from HTTPS to HTTP.
 *
 * If you have some SP's on HTTP and IdP is normally on HTTPS, this option
 * enables secure POSTing to HTTP endpoint without warning from browser.
 *
 * For this to work, module.php/core/postredirect.php must be accessible
 * also via HTTP on IdP, e.g. if your IdP is on
 * https://idp.example.org/ssp/, then
 * http://idp.example.org/ssp/module.php/core/postredirect.php must be accessible.
 */
'enable.http_post' => FALSE,

/*
 * Options to override the default settings for php sessions.
 */
'session.phpsession.cookiename'  => null,
'session.phpsession.savepath'    => null,
'session.phpsession.httponly'    => FALSE,

/*
 * Option to override the default settings for the auth token cookie
 */
'session.authtoken.cookiename' => 'SimpleSAMLAuthToken',

/*
 * Languages available, RTL languages, and what language is default
 */
'language.available'    => array('en', 'no', 'nn', 'se', 'da', 'de', 'sv', 'fi', 'es', 'fr', 'it', 'nl', 'lb', 'cs', 'sl', 'lt', 'hr', 'hu', 'pl', 'pt', 'pt-br', 'tr', 'ja', 'zh', 'zh-tw', 'ru', 'et', 'he', 'id', 'sr'),
'language.rtl'      => array('ar','dv','fa','ur','he'),
'language.default'      => 'fr',

/**
 * Custom getLanguage function called from SimpleSAML_XHTML_Template::getLanguage().
 * Function should return language code of one of the available languages or NULL.
 * See SimpleSAML_XHTML_Template::getLanguage() source code for more info.
 *
 * This option can be used to implement a custom function for determining
 * the default language for the user.
 *
 * Example:
 *   'language.get_language_function' => array('sspmod_example_Template', 'getLanguage'),
 */

/*
 * Extra dictionary for attribute names.
 * This can be used to define local attributes.
 *
 * The format of the parameter is a string with <module>:<dictionary>.
 *
 * Specifying this option will cause us to look for modules/<module>/dictionaries/<dictionary>.definition.json
 * The dictionary should look something like:
 *
 * {
 *     "firstattribute": {
 *         "en": "English name",
 *         "no": "Norwegian name"
 *     },
 *     "secondattribute": {
 *         "en": "English name",
 *         "no": "Norwegian name"
 *     }
 * }
 *
 * Note that all attribute names in the dictionary must in lowercase.
 *
 * Example: 'attributes.extradictionary' => 'ourmodule:ourattributes',
 */
'attributes.extradictionary' => NULL,

/*
 * Which theme directory should be used?
 */
'theme.use'         => 'default',


/*
 * Default IdP for WS-Fed.
 */
'default-wsfed-idp' => 'urn:federation:pingfederate:localhost',

/*
 * Whether the discovery service should allow the user to save his choice of IdP.
 */
'idpdisco.enableremember' => TRUE,
'idpdisco.rememberchecked' => TRUE,

// Disco service only accepts entities it knows.
'idpdisco.validate' => TRUE,

'idpdisco.extDiscoveryStorage' => NULL, 

/*
 * IdP Discovery service look configuration. 
 * Wether to display a list of idp or to display a dropdown box. For many IdP' a dropdown box  
 * gives the best use experience.
 * 
 * When using dropdown box a cookie is used to highlight the previously chosen IdP in the dropdown.  
 * This makes it easier for the user to choose the IdP
 * 
 * Options: [links,dropdown]
 * 
 */
'idpdisco.layout' => 'dropdown',

/*
 * Whether simpleSAMLphp should sign the response or the assertion in SAML 1.1 authentication
 * responses.
 *
 * The default is to sign the assertion element, but that can be overridden by setting this
 * option to TRUE. It can also be overridden on a pr. SP basis by adding an option with the
 * same name to the metadata of the SP.
 */
'shib13.signresponse' => TRUE,



/*
 * Authentication processing filters that will be executed for all IdPs
 * Both Shibboleth and SAML 2.0
 */
'authproc.idp' => array(
    /* Enable the authproc filter below to add URN Prefixces to all attributes
    10 => array(
        'class' => 'core:AttributeMap', 'addurnprefix'
    ), */
    /* Enable the authproc filter below to automatically generated eduPersonTargetedID. 
    20 => 'core:TargetedID',
    */

    // Adopts language from attribute to use in UI
    30 => 'core:LanguageAdaptor',

    /* Add a realm attribute from edupersonprincipalname
    40 => 'core:AttributeRealm',
     */
    45 => array(
        'class' => 'core:StatisticsWithAttribute',
        'attributename' => 'realm',
        'type' => 'saml20-idp-SSO',
    ),

    /* When called without parameters, it will fallback to filter attributes ‹the old way›
     * by checking the 'attributes' parameter in metadata on IdP hosted and SP remote.
     */
    50 => 'core:AttributeLimit', 

    /* 
     * Search attribute "distinguishedName" for pattern and replaces if found

    60 => array(
        'class'     => 'core:AttributeAlter',
        'pattern'   => '/OU=studerende/',
        'replacement'   => 'Student',
        'subject'   => 'distinguishedName',
        '%replace', 
    ),
     */

    /*
     * Consent module is enabled (with no permanent storage, using cookies).

    90 => array(
        'class'     => 'consent:Consent', 
        'store'     => 'consent:Cookie', 
        'focus'     => 'yes', 
        'checked'   => TRUE
    ),
     */
    // If language is set in Consent module it will be added as an attribute.
    99 => 'core:LanguageAdaptor',
),
/*
 * Authentication processing filters that will be executed for all SPs
 * Both Shibboleth and SAML 2.0
 */
'authproc.sp' => array(
    /*
    10 => array(
        'class' => 'core:AttributeMap', 'removeurnprefix'
    ),
    */

    /*
     * Generate the 'group' attribute populated from other variables, including eduPersonAffiliation.
     */
    60 => array('class' => 'core:GenerateGroups', 'eduPersonAffiliation'),
    // All users will be members of 'users' and 'members'   
    61 => array('class' => 'core:AttributeAdd', 'groups' => array('users', 'members')),

    // Adopts language from attribute to use in UI
    90 => 'core:LanguageAdaptor',

),


/*
 * This option configures the metadata sources. The metadata sources is given as an array with
 * different metadata sources. When searching for metadata, simpleSAMPphp will search through
 * the array from start to end.
 *
 * Each element in the array is an associative array which configures the metadata source.
 * The type of the metadata source is given by the 'type' element. For each type we have
 * different configuration options.
 *
 * Flat file metadata handler:
 * - 'type': This is always 'flatfile'.
 * - 'directory': The directory we will load the metadata files from. The default value for
 *                this option is the value of the 'metadatadir' configuration option, or
 *                'metadata/' if that option is unset.
 *
 * XML metadata handler:
 * This metadata handler parses an XML file with either an EntityDescriptor element or an
 * EntitiesDescriptor element. The XML file may be stored locally, or (for debugging) on a remote
 * web server.
 * The XML hetadata handler defines the following options:
 * - 'type': This is always 'xml'.
 * - 'file': Path to the XML file with the metadata.
 * - 'url': The url to fetch metadata from. THIS IS ONLY FOR DEBUGGING - THERE IS NO CACHING OF THE RESPONSE.
 *
 *
 * Examples:
 *
 * This example defines two flatfile sources. One is the default metadata directory, the other
 * is a metadata directory with autogenerated metadata files.
 *
 * 'metadata.sources' => array(
 *     array('type' => 'flatfile'),
 *     array('type' => 'flatfile', 'directory' => 'metadata-generated'),
 *     ),
 *
 * This example defines a flatfile source and an XML source.
 * 'metadata.sources' => array(
 *     array('type' => 'flatfile'),
 *     array('type' => 'xml', 'file' => 'idp.example.org-idpMeta.xml'),
 *     ),
 *
 *
 * Default:
 * 'metadata.sources' => array(
 *     array('type' => 'flatfile')
 *     ),
 */
'metadata.sources' => array(
    array('type' => 'flatfile'),
),


/*
 * Configure the datastore for simpleSAMLphp.
 *
 * - 'phpsession': Limited datastore, which uses the PHP session.
 * - 'memcache': Key-value datastore, based on memcache.
 * - 'sql': SQL datastore, using PDO.
 *
 * The default datastore is 'phpsession'.
 *
 * (This option replaces the old 'session.handler'-option.)
 */
'store.type' => 'phpsession',


/*
 * The DSN the sql datastore should connect to.
 *
 * See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php for the various
 * syntaxes.
 */
'store.sql.dsn' => 'sqlite:/path/to/sqlitedatabase.sq3',

/*
 * The username and password to use when connecting to the database.
 */
'store.sql.username' => NULL,
'store.sql.password' => NULL,

/*
 * The prefix we should use on our tables.
 */
'store.sql.prefix' => 'simpleSAMLphp',


/*
 * Configuration for the MemcacheStore class. This allows you to store
 * multiple redudant copies of sessions on different memcache servers.
 *
 * 'memcache_store.servers' is an array of server groups. Every data
 * item will be mirrored in every server group.
 *
 * Each server group is an array of servers. The data items will be
 * load-balanced between all servers in each server group.
 *
 * Each server is an array of parameters for the server. The following
 * options are available:
 *  - 'hostname': This is the hostname or ip address where the
 *    memcache server runs. This is the only required option.
 *  - 'port': This is the port number of the memcache server. If this
 *    option isn't set, then we will use the 'memcache.default_port'
 *    ini setting. This is 11211 by default.
 *  - 'weight': This sets the weight of this server in this server
 *    group. http://php.net/manual/en/function.Memcache-addServer.php
 *    contains more information about the weight option.
 *  - 'timeout': The timeout for this server. By default, the timeout
 *    is 3 seconds.
 *
 * Example of redudant configuration with load balancing:
 * This configuration makes it possible to lose both servers in the
 * a-group or both servers in the b-group without losing any sessions.
 * Note that sessions will be lost if one server is lost from both the
 * a-group and the b-group.
 *
 * 'memcache_store.servers' => array(
 *     array(
 *         array('hostname' => 'mc_a1'),
 *         array('hostname' => 'mc_a2'),
 *     ),
 *     array(
 *         array('hostname' => 'mc_b1'),
 *         array('hostname' => 'mc_b2'),
 *     ),
 * ),
 *
 * Example of simple configuration with only one memcache server,
 * running on the same computer as the web server:
 * Note that all sessions will be lost if the memcache server crashes.
 *
 * 'memcache_store.servers' => array(
 *     array(
 *         array('hostname' => 'localhost'),
 *     ),
 * ),
 *
 */
'memcache_store.servers' => array(
    array(
        array('hostname' => 'localhost'),
    ),
),


/*
 * This value is the duration data should be stored in memcache. Data
 * will be dropped from the memcache servers when this time expires.
 * The time will be reset every time the data is written to the
 * memcache servers.
 *
 * This value should always be larger than the 'session.duration'
 * option. Not doing this may result in the session being deleted from
 * the memcache servers while it is still in use.
 *
 * Set this value to 0 if you don't want data to expire.
 *
 * Note: The oldest data will always be deleted if the memcache server
 * runs out of storage space.
 */
'memcache_store.expires' =>  36 * (60*60), // 36 hours.


/*
 * Should signing of generated metadata be enabled by default.
 *
 * Metadata signing can also be enabled for a individual SP or IdP by setting the
 * same option in the metadata for the SP or IdP.
 */
'metadata.sign.enable' => TRUE,

/*
 * The default key & certificate which should be used to sign generated metadata. These
 * are files stored in the cert dir.
 * These values can be overridden by the options with the same names in the SP or
 * IdP metadata.
 *
 * If these aren't specified here or in the metadata for the SP or IdP, then
 * the 'certificate' and 'privatekey' option in the metadata will be used.
 * if those aren't set, signing of metadata will fail.
 */
'metadata.sign.privatekey' => NULL,
'metadata.sign.privatekey_pass' => NULL,
'metadata.sign.certificate' => NULL,


/*
 * Proxy to use for retrieving URLs.
 *
 * Example:
 *   'proxy' => 'tcp://proxy.example.com:5100'
 */
'proxy' => NULL,

);
```

Comment: I am getting the same error please post if you were able to get around the issue

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Configuring Apache](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-install#section_6) section of the simpleSAMLphp documentation. I believe you probably just don't have the alias setup.

Answer (score 0):

You should omit the 'www/' from the baseurlpath in config.php as your Apache  Alias already points to that directory.

Comment: I have omited the www but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

If it's helpfull in any way at this point, i was getting the same error.
I had wamp and in the http-vhosts.config i  had :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wwx.saml22.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/wwx.saml22.com/www"
    <Directory  "C:/wamp64/www/wwx.saml22.com/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

wwx.saml22.com is the directory that had the entire project inside, www should be visible to the word.

And for the base path in the config.php file i added

```
'baseurlpath' => '/',
```

After this it worked.